# How to access a method by inheritance of @protocols in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, protocols

I have a program where inheritance of protocols are there say:

```
@protocol A
-(void)methodA
@end
```

The protocol which inherits:

```
@protocol B<A>
-(void)methodB
@end
```

The class which implements @protocolA method is

```
@interface classB<B>

@end

@implementation classB
-(void)methodA
{
  //somecode
}
@end
```

Now i wanted the methodA to be called from Some other class:

```
    @implementation SomeotherClass

{
   //call of methodA
   //????

id<A>obj=[[classB alloc]init];//i have tried it
[obj methodA];// even this is not working 
}
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Just send the message as usual:

```
SomeotherClass *obj = [[[SomeotherClass alloc] init] autorelease];
[obj methodA];
```

Since instances of classB implement protocol B, they also claim to respond to -methodA.
The following compiles and runs without any problems:

**MyClass.h:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol A
-(void) methodA;
@end

@protocol B <A>
-(void) methodB;
@end

@interface MyClass : NSObject <B>
{
}

@end
```

**MyClass.m:**

```
#import "MyClass.h"

@implementation MyClass

-(void) methodA
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}

-(void) methodB
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}

@end
```

**the code:**

```
MyClass *obj = [[MyClass alloc] init];
[obj methodA];
[obj methodB];
[obj release];
```

Comment: I have tried, it is not working. I am not able to access it even if i call the method through the object of protocolA.
I have edited my question at the last part.Pls suggest me how to solve the problem....

Comment: What exactly is happening? Compiler complaining, linker failing or the program crashing?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, at ending of the code i want to access the method in another class not in MyClass where i implement the method.I want that method to be called in a class where i dont implement that method and where the protocol<B>/<A> is not extended.How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say *how* it fails to work. I would guess that there's a compilation error as you don't implement `methodB` in your `classB`.

Another possibility: what happens after you've initialised `classB` in `SomeOtherClass`? Are you sure that you get a valid object back? If it returned a `nil` the run time would be perfectly within its rights to do nothing when you sent the `methodA` message to it.